# read a file a jar

Tags: java, classpath

Is it possible to read a file within a jar ?

My project structure look like this:

```
Root:

 ->src

 ->lib -<my.jar>
```

In the lib directory there is a jar(my.jar) that contain text file

This is the class path in the manifest file:
Class-Path: ./lib/my.jar

and i am trying to load the text file like this:

```
 InputStream in = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/text.license");
```

Any idea how to read the file ?

Thanks

Comment: Within the text file, what is path to the `text.license`?  Is the `my.jar` within the class path of the project?

Comment: the txt file is in the jar root (my - > text.license)
my.jar is in the class-path : Class-Path: ./lib/my.jar

Comment: Where is `Class-Path` defined?  If it's defined in `my.jar` it's meaningless

Comment: Root project -> META-INF->MANIFEST.MF

Comment: Make sure that the `my.jar` is available to the project within IDE (if you're using) and is in the `lib` directory DIRECTLY under you application Jar for execution (outside the IDE)

Comment: I don't get your problem: if you can get the input stream for that text file, you can simply use that input stream to read the content.  What is the problem you are facing? the input stream is not working? or your "read" means something different?

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html

Your best bet would to use the JarFile class
(handles zip compression)